# Integer variables pass by value, string variables by reference?

Tags: ruby, immutability

Modifications made to `b` below are also made to `a`:

```
a = 'taco'
b = a
b << 's'
a #=> tacos
```

When I assign a variable `x` by pointing it at another variable `y`, `x` remains a shortcut to `y`; `x` and `y` will be identical. This seems confirmed by the `dup` method; by saying `b = a.dup`, `b` gets `a`'s value at the moment of assignment rather than a shortcut.

But this doesn't happen with integers. When I assign `b`, it seems to be getting the value of `a`:

```
a = 4815
b = a
b /= 2
a #=> 4815
```

It seems like string variables pass by reference while integer variables pass by value. That doesn't seem right; I know something is wrong in my understanding, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Pass by value / pass by reference refers to method arguments. In your examples, the arguments are `'s'` and `2` and none of them is altered.

Comment: The difference here is that `String#<<` modifies the receiver, i.e. the string instance that's assigned to both, `a` and `b`. `Fixnum#/` on the other hand returns a new `Integer` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between *variables* and *values*. A *variable* points to a *value*. Multiple variables can point to the same value.

In Ruby, the *only* way to modify a variable is via assignment, either simple

```
foo = :something
```

or compound assignment

```
foo ω= :something # for some operator ω
# e.g.
foo += :something
foo <<= :something
foo ||= :something
```

If you modify a *value*, that modification will be visible no matter what variable you use to access that value.

Think about it this way: my mum calls me "son", my friends call me "Jörg", my close friends call me "jwm", my band colleagues call me "Jörgislaw", my girlfriend calls me "baby", but no matter what they call me, if I cut my hair, my hair will be gone, regardless of what name they use to refer to me. If, however, my girlfriend assigns a new value to the label "baby", then that does not affect me. (Well … bear with me, it's an analogy :-D )

In Ruby, `<<` typically modifies the receiver, whereas `/` doesn't.

However, Ruby is *always* pass-by-value. But the value being passed is a pointer to a value, so that multiple variables can contain multiple copies of the same pointer to the same value.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, @JorgWMittag. It helps a lot -- the "pass by value, but the value is a pointer" thing had been confusing me, and this really clears it up.

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of what you are arguing, `b /= 2` is a syntax sugar for `b = b / 2`. Thus, the new `b` is `b / 2` (or `a / 2`), which has nothing to do with `a`.

Comment: I'm aware of this. But in my string example, if I say `b += 's'` (as you say, sugar for `b = b + 's'`, *that* affects `a`. That's the discrepancy that interests me.

Comment: @GreenTriangle No, it doesn't. As long as you are using the `...=` shorthand, it doesn't.

Comment: It depends: `b += 's'` assigns a new string instance, whereas  `b <<= 's'` re-assigns the same string instance.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for correction. I didn't know `<<=` was syntactically possible.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct, see [`Fixnum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html):

> `Fixnum` objects have immediate value. This means that when they are assigned or passed as parameters, the actual object is passed, rather than a reference to that object.
>
> Assignment does not alias `Fixnum` objects. There is effectively only one `Fixnum` object instance for any given integer value, so, for example, you cannot add a singleton method to a `Fixnum`. Any attempt to add a singleton method to a `Fixnum` object will raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: I believe the following also have immediate values: symbols, true, false, and nil.